# Browser and Java Compatibility

Tags: java, browser

Which is the last version of Firefox,Chrome and Internet Explorer that is compatible with Java 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I don't know the reason you ask this whatever I feel this is related to a solution you work on or something anyway refer here if you really need it! http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/index-jsp-136246.html
The latest system requirements!
http://java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml